# Addition in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to add some java variables in html using jsp.

html

```
.... name="Editbox1" value="<%=a %>" spellcheck="false">
```

I have 7 boxes. From a to g. 
At the end of the code, i have a button that should add these, but it wont.

```
input type="submit" id="Button1"  onclick="<% sum = a+b+c+d+e+f+g; %> "
```

when this buton does its thing, the answer should be seen in the editbox number 8.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing things that cannot mix - JSP code runs on the server (it is basically a servlet), while html/js code runs on the client (browser).

When the JSP file is processed on the server, all `<% ... %>` tags are replaced by their evaluated results, and in the end only the html/js is returned to the client.

For this reason, if you take a look at the source code in your browser, you'll see the `onclick` handler is defined with an empty string - the JSP code evaluates to nothing.

If you want to summarize values on button click, you'll either have to do it in JavaScript, or send a new request to the server to get the result.

Comment: I never got to say thank you. Thank you for your help. :)